# Tensorboard negatively affects training process

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Tensorflow-gpu version: 1.8.0
I wanted to view the weights and activations while training a shallow CNN network, and added tf.summary.histogram() everywhere where there is weight and convolution. The way I added is something like this.

In CNN.py

```
def _conv(self, x, ksize, c_out, stride=1, padding='SAME', name='conv'):
    c_in = x.get_shape().as_list()[1]
    W = self._get_variable([ksize, ksize, c_in, c_out], name)
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, self._arr(stride), padding=padding, data_format='NCHW', name=name)
    tf.summary.histogram(name+"activation",x)
    self.H.append(x)
    return x
```

In Train.py

```
  sess = Option.sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
  merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
  train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('../summary',sess.graph)
```

and

```
for batchNum in tqdm(xrange(batchNumTrain), desc='Epoch: %03d' % epoch, leave=False, smoothing=0.1):
      if Option.debug is False:
        _, loss_delta, error_delta,summary = sess.run([train_op, lossTrainBatch, errorTrainBatch, merged])
        train_writer.add_summary(summary,batchNum)
```

The problem is that compared to not adding Tensorbaord, adding these makes the loss look weird. The first epoch was OK, but then it then decreases very slowly compared to not adding Tensorboard.

Am I using Tensorboard the wrong way?

Comment: Please format your code correctly